# Using the word "Windows" as part of your own namespace in Metro style apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

If you try to use Windows as part of your own namespace in Metro-style apps (e.g. MyCompany.Windows) it seems that it throws compiler(s) off, because they start looking for WinRT stuff under your namespace rather than Windows.*.

For example, if you create a blank Windows Metro style app named App1 and rename App1 namespace to be App1.Windows and try to compile it you'll get an error:

The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'App1.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) F:\temp\App1\App1\obj\Debug\App.g.i.cs

the top of the generated file looks like this:

```
namespace App1.Windows
{
#if !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_MAIN
    public static class Program
    {
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 4.0.0.0")]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Start((p) => new App());
        }
    }
#endif

    partial class App : Windows.UI.Xaml.Application
```

and the problem is that compiler starts looking for Windows.UI under App1.Windows.

Now this is nothing new and if you'd name your namespace App1.System before you would probably get into a similar kind of trouble at some point. The problem is that quite a lot of WPF/Silverlight/Windows Phone code out there uses MyCompany.Windows.Xyz namespaces and is probably susceptible to this kind of trouble.

Is there some guidance from Microsoft (can't seem to find one) as to what to do with these namespaces? Or maybe there are some plans on resolving this in future versions? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: that's an auto-generated code from compiler. I have no control over it.

Comment: then for now don't use Windows. Submit bug to connect.microsoft.com and maybe in RTM you'll have the fix

Comment: Yeah, but that's probably not a bug. You'd get into the same trouble in any version of .NET if you use top level namespace (like System) in your own namespace. It's just that many have used Windows in WPF/SL/WP

Comment: in dataset generators or in XSD.exe MS use global::. Maybe now they choose convention over configuration approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at this issue and we should be using global:: in the generated code. We have fixed this on our end and will be available in next release of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known behavior in the C# language specification.  Basically whenever a namespace appears in a "using" clause, the system treats all the elements in the namespace as if they might be part of the using namespace. There are two workarounds: Remove the name "Windows" from the inner nodes in your type or remove the "using" directive.

This is unfortunately not a winrt issue, you can get the same thing to happen with pure CLR applications.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've stated in the question that it's no new or specific to WinRT, it's just that there was no top level Windows namespace before and it was common for WPF/SL/WP7 libraries to use MyCompany.Windows style of namespaces. And now they have to be renamed to avoid troubles. Oh, well, I guess there's no other way.

Comment: It's unfortunate.  FWIW, I had the same issue with a bunch of internal code that I had to rewrite when we created the Windows.winmd file that is in the SDK - it was not fun to deal with.